# Facing difficulty to inline edit

Tags: javascript, jquery, datagrid, inline-editing

I want to create a table where rows will be editable by inline. Tables are created using HTML and data are fetch from database. But can't do inline edit total row and after edit save to database.

```
<table width="50%" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">Action</td>
    <td>id</td>
    <td>userName</td>
    <td>Address</td>
    <td>Role</td>
    <td>Active</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Edit</td>
    <td>InlineEdit</td>
    <td>delete</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>apache</td>
    <td>los angeles</td>
    <td>user</td>
    <td>y</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

In second row all data are collect from database. Please help me to solve the difficulty.

Answer (score 1):

Write input tags in between the `<td>` and assign your php variable to value attribute.

```
<table width="50%" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3"><input type="text" value="Action"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="id"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="Username"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="Address"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="Role"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="Active"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I know there need input tags between both <td>. I request to you please  tell me how to solve my difficulty.

Comment: You could give Edit button next to your row and call jquery function onClick of that button.

Comment: You want to enable edit whole row at one click right?

Comment: In which way i will get information that you explain this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64009/discussion-between-amy-and-apache).